# How do I print using my phone?

Tags: printing

I own a Redmi Note 5 Pro. Before the last update (a few months ago). I could print using my phone after connecting it to my printer with a cable. After the recent upgrade, I'm unable to do so, because I get a message that says that I can only wirelessly print now. Here's the screenshot.

[image]

Is there a way for me to be able to print using my phone connecting it with a printer still or is this change from a setting that allowed me to connect a wire with the printer and print permanently gone? If there's a way to get the printer to still work with my phone, that'd be great for my studies.

P. S. My printer doesn't support wireless printing. It is an EPSON L3100 printer. I've tried apps such as Epson iPrinting and NokoPrint (it's just a highly rated app). Neither of these worked.

Here's a screenshot of the details of my phone

[image]